# refresh selectonechoice data after deleting in other place

Tags: oracle-adf

There are two open tabs pageA and pageB, in pageB there is a `selectOneChoice` whose data is based on pageA, when I delete one piece of data on pageA, then go back to pageB, the deleted data is still in `selectOneChoice` list.

Is there any way to refresh `selectOneChoice` data when going back to pageB?

Comment: Where is the data for selectOneChoice coming from, is it from database or based in-memory values?

Comment: Have you tried putting a partialTrigger on the selectOneChoice on pageB pointing at pageA control that executes the delete? Otherwise you can put listener on tabB so when user goes to it, you do the work in the backing bean.